# NoClassDefFoundError running java from the console

Tags: java, linux, terminal

When I tried to run Java on Linux on the terminal this is what happens:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorldApp/class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorldApp.class
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Can anyone help me with this?

EDIT: I was in the folder of the bytecode file and ran this on the terminal:

```
bash-4.1$ java class HelloWorldApp
```

Source file:

```
/**
 * The HelloWorldApp class implements an application that
 * simply prints "Hello World!" to standard output.
 */
class HelloWorldApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Display the string.
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah show how you run it. Did you name the class same as the file ?

Comment: How are you running this? did you make sure to add the current directory from which the program is being executed, to the classpath? something like this: java -classpath . HelloWorldApp Alternatively, it's possible that you placed the file in the wrong package, or that the name of the file doesn't match the name of the public class it contains.

Comment: Some newer versions of java require the classes to be in a package, and by the looks of the error message, your class is not in a package.

Comment: have you compiled you HelloWorldApp.java class so that it creates a HelloWorldApp.class file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing

`java HelloWorldApp.class`

but it must be

`java HelloWorldApp`

You may not append class to your call but name plain the classname.

Also, as others has remarked, it is better to use packages as classes in the default package do not work fine.

Answer (score -1):

You also should note that if you have the package declaration in the code it will screw it up even if you try all the fancy fixes like setting CLASSPATH.  For example if you have:

```
package blah;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

The line:   package blah;
will cause java HelloWorld to fail after compiling.  So remove this line and you should be able to run the src via cmd line.